# Crazy Django Error - Variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django, django-views

Trying to create a django application but getting an `UnboundLocalError at /search/ local variable 'results' referenced before assignment` error. I can't see the problem as in my code results is assigned - have a look:

```
def post_search(request):
    form = SearchForm()
    if 'query' in request.GET:
        form = SearchForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            results = SearchQuerySet().models(Post).filter(content=cd['query']).load_all()
            # count total results
            total_results = results.count()
    return render(request, 'blog/post/search.html', {'form': form,
                                                 'cd': cd,
                                                 'results': results,
                                                 'total_results': total_results})
```

Comment: I'm really new to Django - just following a tutorial

Comment: What should I do to fix it

Comment: But that's just a basic Python thing, it's got nothing to do with Django. Are you also new to Python?

Comment: Fairly - I understand what you are saying - the variable is not created unless the form is valid, and since it can't be valid until it is created it doesn't work.

Comment: So put the `render()` call inside the `if` block rather than in the `return` statement. If the form is invalid, presumably you want to display an error message, or at least log the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should initialize results.
Put `results = []` before `if form.is_valid()`

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want to do if there are no results. Do you still want to load the view? Then initialise the `results` variable above any `if` condition (in this case, the outer one):

```
...
results = [] #Or whatever empty datatype you need
if 'query' in request.GET:
   ...
```

If you don't want to load the view if there are no results, you could move the `return render(...)` inside the inner `if` when you're **sure** there is a `results` variable to begin with. Then, you can add a fallback `return render(...)` at the end of the function, outside of any `if` conditions.

If you always want to load the same view, however, I'd just go for the first one. Adding multiple `return render(...)` seems more suitable when you want to load a different view when no results were found.

Answer (score 2):

What if `form` is invalid? For example, user provided incorrect value on no value at all? In this case `results` is uninitialized. You may:

1. Initialize it with some empty value like `[]`.
2. Raise error and return to user info that form is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

```
def post_search(request):
    cd = ""
    total_results = ""
    form = SearchForm()
    if 'query' in request.GET:
        form = SearchForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            results = SearchQuerySet().models(Post).filter(content=cd['query']).load_all()
            # count total results
            total_results = results.count()
    return render(request, 'blog/post/search.html', {'form': form,
                                                 'cd': cd,
                                                 'results': results,
                                                 'total_results': total_results})
```

now you have to write validation code in template

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the definition in a recursive way(count the results in your case) you should assign the var results outside the definition, because if you do it will reset every time you call it. You have to assign it out of the definition and state it like a global var.

```
global results 
results = ''
```

I personally recommend you to do a bit more reading and learning on python before coding with Django.

Good luck ! :)

Comment: There is almost never a reason to declare global variables in python. A simple result variable in this case can easily be handled within the scope of this function.

Comment: Can you please be a little more specific ?            If he wants to do iteration with the function, the var result will be reset every time the function is called, plus if the var results is declared as global, it can be used in other functions and the value the var got on the first function isn't changed in the ones to come. That's why I proposed to declare the var results as global.

Comment: "If he wants to do iteration with the function" What do you mean by this?

Comment: This function loads a view. The results are queried from the database to probably be formatted into some template. If this value is so essential it needs to be accessible from anywhere, it should not even be initialised here, but someplace else. Using a global variable for this is pointless. You can read more on this [here][http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil]